# Getting No Urls to Fetch error on Nutch1.16

Tags: nutch

I am new to `apache-nutch` and want to crawl few questions on `stackoverflow`. My `urls/seed.txt` has following data:-

```
/questions/58763948/setting-a-list-item-is-converting-it-into-a-tuple
/questions/58763947/start-up-eclipse-an-error-has-occured-see-the-log-file
/questions/58763946/problem-with-the-proxy-using-zap-docker-image-gitlab
/questions/58763945/how-to-select-unique-random-data-based-on-percent-in-sql
/questions/58763943/probelm-with-using-filter-function-to-remove-missing-values-form-a-dataset
/questions/58763942/flutter-keep-data-in-textfield-after-setstate
/questions/58763941/are-receipts-generated-by-google-play-api-v2-and-the-latest-version-v3-compatibl
/questions/58763940/how-to-add-eventhandler-to-popupmenuitem-in-flutter
/questions/58763938/how-to-solve-electron-and-grpc-version-problem-in-angular-project
...
```

Is there any `property` which i can include in `nutch-site.xml` to add `https://stackoverflow.com` before every url in `seed.txt`. I don't want to change `seed.txt` since file is large

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such configuration property. It's possible to do this by adding the following rule to `regex-normalize.xml`:

```
<regex>
  <pattern>^/</pattern>
  <substitution>https://stackoverflow.com/</substitution>
</regex>
```

Also make sure that the plugin `urlnormalizer-regex` is included in the property `plugin.includes`.